# Perl 6: maxpairs warns about stringification of undefined values

Tags: raku, rakudo

It looks like `maxpairs` doesn't like to be called on a list with undefined values:

```
> my @foo; @foo[2] = 4; say @foo.maxpairs;
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

(2 => 4)
```

`max` doesn't have the same issue and seems to simply ignore undefined values:

```
> my @foo; @foo[2] = 4; say @foo.max;
4
```

The same error does occur with:

```
> my @foo; @foo[2] = 4; say @foo.pairs.max(*.value)
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

2 => 4
```

So it appears that undefined values are only ignored when using `max` without a filter parameter.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like one to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this looks like a bug, I've fixed it with

```
https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/7bf7a2c6f83a57713c
```

Which also takes care of "minpairs".